# R Why do I have to assign a formal argument variable to itself in order for this function to work?

Tags: r

I have developed the following two functions:

```
save_sysdata <- function(...) {
  data <- eval(substitute(alist(...)))
  data <- purrr::map_chr(data, add_dot)
  save(list = data, file = "sysdata.rda", compress = "bzip2", version = 2)
}

add_dot <- function(object) {
  object <- object # Why is this required?
  name <- paste0(".", deparse(substitute(object)))
  # parent.frame(3) because evaluating in global (or caller function); 2 because assigning in save_sysdata.
  assign(name, eval(object, envir = parent.frame(3)), envir = parent.frame(2))
  return(name)
}
```

The purpose of this set of functions is to provide an object (`x`) and save it as a `sysdata.rda` file but as a hidden object. This requires adding a `.` to the object symbol (`.x`).

The set of functions as I have it works and accomplishes what I want. However, it requires a bit of code that I don't understand why it works or what it's doing. I'm not even sure how I came up with this particular line as a solution.

If I remove the line `object <- object` from the `add_dot` function, the whole thing fails to work. It actually just generates an empty `sysdata.rda` file.

**Can anyone explain why this line is necessary and what it is doing?**

And if you have a more efficient way of accomplishing this, please let me know. It was a fun exercise to figure this out myself but I'm sure there is a better way.

For a reprex, simply copy the above functions and run:

```
x <- "test"
save_sysdata(x)
```

Then load the `sysdata.rda` file into your global environment and type `.x`. You should return `[1] "test"`.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work without it? That instruction is useless.

Comment: Yes, positive. I thought it was useless too, but give it a try.

Comment: Already have. I have included the lines `obj <- deparse1(substitute(object)); cat("obj:", obj, "\n\n")` right at the beginning of `add_dot` and `cat("obj2:", object, "\n\n")` after the non-sense instruction. Maybe the answer is there. The first print is expected, btw.

Comment: Very interesting. I wonder why it occurs like that. Something to do with evaluating the `object` in the function scope. I'll see if I can figure it out and articulate it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative version

```
save_sysdata <- function(...)  {
  pnames <- sapply(match.call(expand.dots=FALSE)$..., deparse)
  snames <- paste0(".", pnames)
  senv <- setNames(list(...), snames)
  save(list = snames, envir=list2env(senv), file = "sysdata.rda", compress = "bzip2", version = 2)
}
```

We dump the values into a named list and granbing the names of the parameter with `match.call()`. We add dots to the names and then turn that list into an environment that we can use with save.

The reason your version required `object <- object` is that function parameters are lazily evaluated. Since you never actually use the value of that object in your function without the assignment, it remains a promise and is never added tot he function environment. Sometimes you'll see `force(object)` instead which does the same thing.